# Prolog: what is the - prefix in predicates / variables?

Tags: prolog, prefix

Example:

```
conditions([-on(a, b)]).
```

I have searched tirelessly but fruitlessly for the meaning of this and the + prefix. You are my last hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No context is provided, so I'm supposing this might come from something in documentation.

If you read the introductory material in the Prolog manual (SWI, Gnu, or whichever) they describe teh conventions. The `+`, `-`, and `?` are used as a convention in documentation to indicate whether an variable is an input or an output or a variable (either). For example, from the Gnu Prolog manual:

`+`: the argument must be instantiated.

`-`: the argument must be a variable (will be instantiated if the built-in predicate succeeds).

`?`: the argument can be instantiated or a variable.

So, for example, `atom_length/2` is described as;

```
atom_length(+atom, ?integer)
```

Which means you must provide `atom` (it can't be a variable) and `integer` can either be a variable (in which case `atom_length` will provide a value) or it can be instantiated (in which case `atom_length` will indicate whether your query is true or false)`.

You don't normally use the `-` or `+` in your code in this sense, unless you really intend to have it there as part of your term. Considering the given example, it looks like it may have been an intended part of the term:

```
conditions([-on(a, b)]).
```

The list parameter consists of a term, when spelled out fully, is `-(on(a,b))` (`-/1` with parameter that's `on/2`). The `-` here doesn't provide any function, it just adds structure (the structure being a term with name `-` and parameter `on(a,b)`).

Comment: I had read that bit about mode spec, but it only confused me further. Your explanation of my example though was the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much for that mbratch!

Comment: @ajc yes, sorry if I sidetracked on the documentation thing. At first I was thinking it was one of those points of confusion but then realized, based upon your example, it probably wasn't. But I left all that there for completeness. I'm glad the answer finally helped. :)

Comment: @lurker Hello. The documentation part interests me. I would like to know if  the +, -, ? etc. are just some notations and they do not actually restrict you from querying something like p(X, Y) , where p is a predicat with the the following header: p(+X, -Y) and the query could even work. In this case the predicat should have better been 'defined' as p(?X, -Y) or am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu as far as the documentation is concerned, these are strictly notational for brevity of expressing the nature of the arguments. Whether using these characters in an actual query works or does something sensible depends upon the character. But you can, for instance, say `-a` which is short for `-(a)` (a term with `-` as the functor, and `a` as a single argument). You cannot use `?` as a functor, however. Prolog doesn't allow it.